# Select between two dates dateformat

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date

Maybe anyone can help me with this query. I just want to select all rows between two dates, but I'm having problems with the date-format.

My query:

```
SELECT id, number, date
FROM `table`
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(date, '%j-%n-%Y') between '6-4-2015' AND '6-4-2016')
```

I don't know what's wrong with this query. I've tried to use `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE`.

The datetype of date is text (and i want like to keep it)

Here's an example of the database:

```
1     233        5-4-2015
2     238        6-4-2015
3     431        7-4-2015
4     230        8-4-2015
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What's the original format?

Comment: show some sample data and what is the datatype of `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong date conversion in `str_to_date` , looks like the dates are in `d-m-Y` format and what you are doing is as

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('5-4-2015', '%j-%n-%Y') ;
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('5-4-2015', '%j-%n-%Y') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
```

So its giving you null and the store ends there.

You should be using

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('5-4-2015', '%d-%m-%Y') ;
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('5-4-2015', '%d-%m-%Y') |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2015-04-05                          |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now the comparison should be as

```
WHERE 
STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y') 
between 
STR_TO_DATE('6-4-2015','%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('6-4-2015','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

> plese try this one strtotime function

```
'.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($r['date'])).'
```

For Example

```
 "select * from sales3 where (sdate between '.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($r['date1'])).' and '.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($r['date2'])).')"
```